# what is "com.google.android.ext.services"

Tags: 7.0-nougat, google, android-device-manager

What is `com.google.android.ext.services`? I accidently found this app in the running list and when I open it contains a settings and then it have opening links option inside it that contains the apps that I have installed in my phone and this help me to disable some of Google apps that I can't do in settings.

I have provided the screen shots of my phone, I disabled about 4 google apps with this and it can also have the option to disable the sytem's important apps like "message" etc. When I searched it in google and mi community I can't find anything and I want to know the thing behind this.

It also contains an option "special acces" which contains details about apps usage and battery optimisations etc.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

com.google.android.ext.services is a package found in [Gapps](https://github.com/opengapps/all/tree/master/priv-app/com.google.android.ext.services).

The answer to this previous [questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/169291/247431) should provide the explanation on what the app does.