# How to disable Google Apps in Mi Phones

Tags: google-apps, disable-app, mi

I observed in case of Mi phones like Redmi Note 4 & Mi Max2.

We’re not able to disable Google Apps like Chrome, Play Music, Play Movies & TV, etc.

Please let me know, how to disable Google apps?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't disable it normally in settings or the disable button has been greyed out for some reason then I'd suggest you'd follow this procedure given in this MIUI form thread: [Disable Google Apps In MIUI 8 (and 9)](https://c.mi.com/thread-114433-1-0.html) which I too confirm to be 100% working (tested).

1. Install [Quickshortcutmaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut&h=en) from Playstore
2. Select normal search - under input box type **manage apps** and click search

[image] [image]

3. In search results it will show settings click it, you will find "manage apps" under click then click **try** (or create shortcut by pressing create).

[image]

4. From here a list of installed applications is shown, navigate to the desired google app(s), select the app, and now you can click **disable** button to disable the app.

[image]

**NB: No root is required!**

Acknowledgements

- **[Disable Google Apps In MIUI 8](https://c.mi.com/thread-114433-1-0.html)**

Comment: I just purchased Mi Max 2 and it taken update for MIUI Global 9.2 Stable. Earlier I was trying with steps explained in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188240/what-is-com-google-android-ext-services. I couldn’t find Running Apps. Please let me know how to disable GoogleApps like Chrome, Play Music, Play Movies & TV in Mi Max2 with MIUI Global 9.2 Stable.

Comment: Just follow the same proceedure it works!

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you how I achieved this on my Redmi note 5 pro:

1. Get adb
2. Enable usb debugging, connect your phone to pc.
3. Use adb shell to give this command:

   ```
   pm uninstall --user 0 package_name
   ```
4. This must work, tested on miui 9.2.7.0
5. The apps will come back after factory reset

More info:
[XDA Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/)