# Disable Google Apps in MIUI 9 and MIUI 9.5

Tags: miui, mi

My friend has two Mi phones Redmi Note4 and Mi Max2.

And recently I updated both; Redmi Note 4 to MIUI 9 and Mi Max2 to MIUI 9.5.

To disable Google Apps like Chrome, Play Music, Play Movies & TV, etc in both I gone through the [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188240/what-is-com-google-android-ext-services). The steps explained the link is for MIUI 8.0. That's why Google Apps couldn't be disabled.

Please let me know how to disable Google Apps in MIUI 9 and MIUI 9.5?

With Regards
TekQ

Comment: For system apps(built-in eg: chrome, google etc), in settings you have two options, disable and force stop. For user apps(installed from playstore), you have uninstall and force stop. These settings are from Stock Android 8.0 Oreo. MIUI 9 on these devices will be running Android 7.0 Nougat and may have above options in settings->Installed apps.

Comment: [Check this for detailed step to disable](http://ttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgKd3qhX2ww)